# Probability that two distinguishable objects to be included

Tags: probability

Say we are distributing 19 distinguishable meals to $7$ distinguishable people, with possible repetition, uniformly at random.  I am assuming $|\Omega|=19^7$.  I am trying to find the probability that two arbitrary meals $a$ and $b$ are both distributed.

I originally thought it would be $\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 19^5}{19^7}$ but I think I am overcounting...

Could it be (edited): $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^{7-i}\binom{7}{i}\binom{7-i}{j}17^{7-i-j}}{19^7}\approx 0.0892414$?  That looks way too complicated.  My thinking is that $i$ represents the number of $a$ meals distributed and $j$ represents the number of $b$ meals distributed (they both must be $\geq$ 1).

Comment: when $i=7$, the second summation doesn't make sense since you can't choose a meal from $b$, and you are overcounting, hence the slightly larger answer when compared to mine. Maybe if $i$ is from 1 to 6?

Comment: Hmm... my edited formula is still slightly higher: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bsum+from+i%3D1+to+6+of+(%5Csum+from+j%3D1+to+(7-i)+of+(7+choose+i)((7-i)+choose+j)17%5E%7B7-i-j%7D)%7D%7B19%5E7%7D

Comment: In fact it comes out to the same thing based on a sum from 1 to 0 evaluating to 0 I guess

Comment: Ah yes, it doesn't make sense to count from 1 to 0 of course, so that case is excluded and you get the same answer. What is the reasoning behind $17^{7-i-j}$?

Comment: I was thinking that, if $i=1$ and $j=1$, for instance, you have 17 choices of dish (not $a$ or $b$) for each of the remaining $7-i-j=5$ people, so $17^5$ choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agreed with your last solution, using another method:

Let's again use the complement argument:

What are the ways that neither $a$ nor $b$ are chosen?

Number of ways $a$ not chosen: $\dfrac{18^7}{19^7}$

Number of ways $b$ not chosen: $\dfrac{18^7}{19^7}$

However, we are counting the event that neither $a$ nor $b$ is chosen twice, so we must deduct $\dfrac{17^7}{19^7}$

So we get:

$$1-\bigg(\dfrac{18^7}{19^7}+\dfrac{18^7}{19^7}-\dfrac{17^7}{19^7}\bigg)=0.08924$$

I think my old answer is incorrect since I am not taking into account the fact that the people are distinguishable, but I'm not sure. If anyone else can confirm this, please do.

OLD ANSWER:

Let $A$ = event that $a$ is chosen and $B$ = event that $b$ is chosen

$$Pr(A)=1-Pr(A^c)=1-\bigg(\dfrac{18}{19}\bigg)^7$$

The last term means that all 7 people must choose something other than meal $a$

$$Pr(B|A)=1-Pr(B^c|A)=1-\bigg(\dfrac{18}{19}\bigg)^6$$

The power in this case is 6 since the first dish is already catered for in the first equation

$$Pr(A, B)=Pr(A)Pr(B|A)=\bigg(1-\bigg(\dfrac{18}{19}\bigg)^7\bigg)\bigg(1-\bigg(\dfrac{18}{19}\bigg)^6\bigg)=0.0873$$

Comment: This comes to a slightly different answer than the one I got... any comment on my proposed solution/why it is different or wrong?

Comment: Actually, are you possibly overcounting $Pr(B^C \mid A)$?  Like meal $a$ being catered to the first person and the second could be an outcome in $A$, and then all the rest being different meals would be counted... but then if the $A$ event is just the first person being given $a$ and then the second person is given $a$ because it is not $b$... those are counted twice, no?

Comment: I'm saying that $A$ means at least one $a$ was distributed, not exactly 1.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I think your first solution is implicitly utilizing De Morgan's law (to get to the statement that the complement is "a is not chosen or b is not chosen") and the principle of inclusion-exclusion for probability.  Much more simple and intuitive than mine.